# Create a table within newenvironment using tblr

Tags: tables, environments, ampersand

I've set up a (3 column) table using the tblr environment and would like to put this in a new environment. Then be able to add additional rows to the table with something like \name{person's name & person's email address & person's location}

I'm using XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=text-text}
\setsansfont{Verdana}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\name{ > { \SplitList{&}} m }
   {%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\MakeEntry}\relax\\%
   }

\newenvironment{distlist}{%
    \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tblr}{width=1\textwidth,
            hline{1,Z} = {0.5pt},
            hline{2} = {3pt},
            hline{3-Y} = {0.5pt,dotted},
            vline{2,3} = {dotted},
            row{1} = {1.1cm},  
            cells = {l,m, fg = black},
            column{1,3}={4cm},
            column{3}={3.1cm},
            column{2}={7.8cm,fg = blue}}
        
        Name& \color{black}Email Address    & Location\\
        }       
        {%
        \end{tblr}
        \end{table}
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{distlist}
\name{Bloggs, Joe & joebloggs@work.com & Europe} \\
\name{Bloggs, Jan & janbloggs@work.com & Europe}\\
\end{distlist}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting multiple undefined control sequence errors and not really sure how to proceed. Happy to hear alternate suggestions.

Comment: Where is `\MakeEntry` defined?

Comment: @SockPile It looks like you have two separate accounts and thus aren't able to post comments. You can use the contact link at the bottom of the slide to get them merged.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks! I have got my accounts merged now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `\name` is doing, when you can more simply input

```
\begin{distlist}
Bloggs, Joe & joebloggs@work.com & Europe \\
Bloggs, Jan & janbloggs@work.com & Europe \\
\end{distlist}
```

Anyway, you can use `\name`, if you prefer, using the `expand` feature. But recall that `tblr` absorbs its contents before starting to typeset and environments defined in terms of `tblr` should do the same.

I removed `table`, because it does nothing more than `center`; I also changed the column specs, because yours were a bit contradictory.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{#1\\}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{distlist}{+b}{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\name]{
    width=1\textwidth,
    colspec={X[1,l] X[2,l] X[1,l]},
    hline{1,Z} = {0.5pt},
    hline{2} = {3pt},
    hline{3-Y} = {0.5pt,dotted},
    vline{2,3} = {dotted},
    row{1} = {1.1cm},
    column{2}={fg = blue},
  }
  Name & \color{black}Email Address & Location\\
  #1
  \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{distlist}
\name{Bloggs, Joe & joebloggs@work.com & Europe}
\name{Bloggs, Jan & janbloggs@work.com & Europe}
\end{distlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't load `lmodern` if you use XeLaTeX.

Comment: Removing the `\DeclareDocumentCommand\name` code block and removing the \name as mentioned in your first line is what I was after. Noted about the use of `lmodern`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your MWE I was a bit surprised: why define new commands and macros when you enter the values to be sorted the same way as you would enter values in the table itself?

Hence I simplified your code so the `tabularray` environment is directly filled in the document itself:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[sans-style=upright]{unicode-math} %-- loads fontspec for use in XeTeX and LuaLaTeX
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont{LinLibertine}[
    Scale=1.00,
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *_R,
    ItalicFont = *_RI,
    BoldFont = *_RB,
    BoldItalicFont = *_RBI]

%\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}


\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{width=1\textwidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {0.5pt},
    hline{2} = {3pt},
    hline{3-Y} = {0.5pt,dotted},
    vline{2,3} = {dotted},
    row{1} = {1.1cm},  
    cells = {l,m, fg = black},
    column{1,3}={4cm},
    column{3}={3.1cm},
    column{2}={7.8cm,fg = blue}
    }%
    Name        & \color{black}Email Address    & Location\\
%=== entries of name / email / location
    Bloggs, Joe & joebloggs@work.com            & Europe \\
    Bloggs, Joe & joebloggs@work.com            & Europe \\
\end{tblr}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Since you are compiling in XeTeX (or LuaLaTeX) I changed the way fonts are loaded. In XeTeX it is customary to use either `fontspec` or -- when math is needed as well -- `unicode-math` (which will load `fontspec`). The legacy fonts like `amsmath` en `lmodern` can be used, but modern fonts like `Libertine` are preferred to benefit from the fonthandling by `fontspec`.

You can find an overview of available fonts on the Catalogue: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

If this is not the answer you were looking for, please edit your question to clarify the use of that sorting macro.

Comment: I am using Verdana, (not my choice, unfortunately) and have updated my question to show how I have loaded it. Sorry wasn't really sure how much to put in a MWE.

Comment: According to Wikipedia's page on Verdana (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdana)  the `DejaVu Sans` fonts are equivalent to Verdana. These fonts happen to be a unicode character set, required by `fontspec`. Maybe you can take a shot at using that font as alternative to Verdana.

Answer (score 2):

- I wonder why you define new environment when you can get the same result with direct use of `tblr`.
- your table is quite wider than default size of `\textwidth` at `article` document class
- If your document is (also) used "online", You may consider to use `url` package for writing e-mail addresses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = {0.5pt},
                      hline{2}   = {3pt},
                      hline{3-Y} = {0.5pt,dotted},
                      vline{2,3} = {dotted},
                          row{1} = {11mm},
                      colspec = {X[l] Q[l, wd=55mm] X[l]}
                    }%
Name        &   Email Address    &  Location\\
%=== entries of name / email / location
Bloggs, Joe & \url{joebloggs@work.com} & Europe \\
Bloggs, Joe & \url{joebloggs@work.com} & Europe \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lined indicate page layout)

**Addendum:**
In case that you prefer to have new environment for your table, see if the following solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrEnviron{distlist}
\SetTblrInner[distlist]{hline{1,Z} = {0.5pt},
                        hline{2}   = {3pt},
                        hline{3-Y} = {0.5pt,dotted},
                        vline{2,3} = {dotted},
                            row{1} = {11mm},
                           colspec = {X[l] Q[l, wd=55mm] X[l]}
                        }

\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{distlist}{}
Name        &   Email Address    &  Location\\
%
Bloggs, Joe & \url{joebloggs@work.com} & Europe \\
Bloggs, Joe & \url{joebloggs@work.com} & Europe \\
         \end{distlist}
\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is the same as before. Using this approach have some benefits if your document has several such tables

Comment: When compiling your first code block I getting 2 errors: 
! LaTeX Error: Command \ShowFrameLinethickness undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \ShowFrameColor undefined.

Comment: @SockPile, than simple delete those three lines.  They only show page layout. I use recent MiKTeX installation and works fine (no errors, no warnings), so I don't know, what is going wrong at you. Do you have installed `showframe` package?

Comment: I deleted those 2 lines and it worked, was prompted to install `showframe` package so I do have that package

Comment: @SockPile, if you have looked MWE of the first example carefully, you should notice that  part of MWE used for shows the page layout, is emphasised by comments *in real document don't use it*. Now it is deleted, since seems to be too disturbing for you. Now the  compilation of MWE should go smooth.